# how to fill a page with table

Tags: tables

I try to calculate amount rows in table at page. Look like it works, but last line in table is wery strange and I do not understand why.

There is code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left= 1 cm, right=1 cm, top = 2 cm, bottom = 1 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{LoopCNT}

\newcommand{\myline}{&&& \\ \hline}

\newcommand{\mysetpos}[1]{%
  \pdfsavepos%
  \write\csname @auxout\endcsname{%
    \string\ifx#1\string\undefined}%
  \write\csname @auxout\endcsname{%
    \string \gdef #1{\the\pdflastypos}}%
  \write\csname @auxout\endcsname{%
    \string\fi%
  }}%
\ifx\zposlast\undefined
  \newcommand{\MYcount}{70}
\else
  \edef\MYcount{\the\numexpr((\zposfirst-\zposprev)/(\zposprev-\zposlast))}
\fi
\providecommand{\zposfirst}{}
\providecommand{\zposprev}{}
\providecommand{\zposlast}{}
\zposfirst; \zposprev; \zposlast; \MYcount

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|c|}
  \hline
  THe&head&line&ypos % \endhead
  \tabularnewline \hline \endhead
  \mysetpos{\string\zposprev}%
  The&foot&line& \\ \hline%
  \mysetpos{\string\zposlast}%
  \endfoot
a &b&c&d \\ \hline
&&&\\ \hline
&&&\\ \hline
&&&\\ \hline
&&&\\ \hline
  \mysetpos{\string\zposfirst}%
  \whiledo{\value{LoopCNT} < \MYcount}{%
    \addtocounter{LoopCNT}{1}\theLoopCNT\myline%
  }
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

And I get in result:

[image: There are unwanted gap above footer and bug under it]

How to fix this?

Comment: why do you need to do this, longtable is calculating teh number of lines that fit already? But the extra cell at the bottom of the foot is because you started a new cell after the `\hline` with `\mysetpos{\string\zposlast}%`  which produces no text but does make a table cell so you see the empty cell.

Comment: I am designing class journal and after filling goup list I need to fill rest of table with blank rows.  The whole idea is gotten from there: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210326/fill-last-page-with-empty-lines-in-longtable-longtabu) but I do not understand some magic (espetialy magic numbers).

If I put `\mysetpos{\string\zposlast}%` before `\hline` I get error _ERROR: Misplaced \noalign_. If I put `\mysetpos{\string\zposlast}%`  before `//` I can not calculate the hight of row... So how to be?

Comment: By the way, is it possible to ask longtable to drop blank rows, wich go on the nex page?

Comment: And what is nature of gap (extra space)  between 47 row and foot row ?

Comment: you could use `\noalign{\mysetpos{\string\zposlast}}`

Comment: It is not a gap it is a row with just one cell, as for the one after the foot you are starting a new cell to do all your loop calculations)

Comment: what placed in this addition sel/row? and why this not placed in foot row?
  PS: placing `\noalign{\mysetpos{\string\zposlast}}` betwin `\\` and `\hline` provide wrong calculation of the row's high

Answer (score 1):

Now I have a solution wich work for me

- I have had to rearenge code --- now I calculate height of first added row not the foot row's height
- The false test wich finish loop generate (start) a сell "without" row, wich look like garbage at the output. so I need to add code, generating full row starting from the cell.

So my table will always have at least 3 extra blank row...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left= 1 cm, right=1 cm, top = 2 cm, bottom = 1 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{LoopCNT}

\newcommand{\myline}{&&& \\ \hline}

\newcommand{\mysetpos}[1]{%
  \pdfsavepos%
%  \rule{.5 cm}{.4pt}%
  \write\csname @auxout\endcsname{%
    \string\ifx#1\string\undefined}%
  \write\csname @auxout\endcsname{%
    \string \gdef #1{\the\pdflastypos}}%
  \write\csname @auxout\endcsname{%
    \string\fi%
  }}%
\ifx\zposlast\undefined
  \newcommand{\MYcount}{70}
 \else
   \edef\MYcount{\the\numexpr((\zposmiddle-\zposlast)/(\zposfirst-\zposmiddle))}
 \fi

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|c|}
  \hline
  THe&head&line&ypos 
  \tabularnewline \hline \endhead
  \mysetpos{\string\zposlast}%
  The&foot&line& \\ \hline%
  \endfoot
a &b&c&d \\ \hline
&&&\\ \hline
&&&\\ \hline
&&&\\ \hline
&&&\\ \hline
  \mysetpos{\string\zposfirst}%
  \whiledo{\value{LoopCNT} < \MYcount}{%
    \addtocounter{LoopCNT}{1}\theLoopCNT\myline%
    \mysetpos{\string\zposmiddle}%
  }
  \myline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there still esthetic question: how add indention to the output in .out file?